# Default metrics for $c_0$ and $l^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, notation, metric-spaces

In my book there is a question like

> Let $\{a^{(k)}\}$ be a convergent sequence of points in $l^1$. Prove that $\{a^{(k)}\}$ converges in $l^{\infty}$.

Now I don't see it mentioned anywhere what metric I should use for $l^{\infty}$. The book only mentions the metric $$d(\{a_n\},\{b_n\})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n-b_n|$$ for $l^1$, and the metric $$d(\{a_n\},\{b_n\})=\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n-b_n)^2}$$ for $l^2$. But it also talks about convergence for $c_0$ (the set of sequences converging to $0$) and $l^{\infty}$ (the set of bounded sequences). Are there default metrics for those two sets?

Comment: On $\ell^\infty$ (bounded sequences), the norm is the sup. So the distance is $d(a,b)=\sup|a_n-b_n|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both $l^\infty$ and its subspace $c_0$, the standard metric is the sup metric $d(a,b)=\sup |a_n-b_n|$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\ell^1\subseteq c_0\subseteq  \ell^\infty$.

For every $m$, $|a_m-b_m|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|a_n-b_n|$. So
$$
d_\infty(a,b)=\sup_{m\geq 1} |a_m-b_m|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|a_n-b_n|=d_1(a,b).
$$
Therefore, if $d_1(a^{(k)},a)\rightarrow 0$, then $d_\infty(a^{(k)},a)\rightarrow 0$. So if $a^{(k)}$ converges to $a$ in $\ell^1$, then the sequence and its limit are all in $\ell^\infty$, and $a^{(k)}$ converges to $a$ in $\ell^\infty$